# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)... after adding react-bulma-components

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am trying to add a `navbar`from the `bulma` CSS framework. Actually, I am using the `react-bulma-components`to achieve this.

So far, I have the following `Header` `React`component:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
    Navbar, NavbarBrand,
    NavbarItem, NavbarMenu, NavbarContainer,
    NavbarBurger, NavbarLink, NavbarDropdown,
    NavbarDivider
} from 'react-bulma-components';



const Header = () => {


    const MyNavbar = <Navbar>
        <NavbarBrand>
            <NavbarItem href="#">
                <img
                    alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox"
                    height="28"
                    src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png"
                    width="112"
                />
            </NavbarItem>
            <NavbarBurger />
        </NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarMenu>
            <NavbarContainer>
                <NavbarItem href="#">
                    <NavbarLink>
                        First
                    </NavbarLink>
                    <NavbarDropdown>
                        <NavbarItem href="#">
                            Subitem 1
                        </NavbarItem>
                        <NavbarItem href="#">
                            Subitem 2
                        </NavbarItem>
                        <NavbarDivider />
                        <NavbarItem href="#">
                            After divider
                        </NavbarItem>
                    </NavbarDropdown>
                </NavbarItem>
                <NavbarItem href="#">
                    Second
                </NavbarItem>
            </NavbarContainer>
            <NavbarContainer align="end">
                <NavbarItem href="#">
                    At the end
                </NavbarItem>
            </NavbarContainer>
        </NavbarMenu>
    </Navbar>

    return (
        <>

            <div className="hero is-danger is bold">
                <div className="hero-body">
                    <div className="container">
                        <h2 className="title is-2"> TEST </h2>
                        <h5 className="title is-5"> test</h5>
                    </div>

                    { MyNavbar }

                </div>
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

If I uncomment the `{ MyNavbar }` it fails with the following error message:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Header`.
```

As I have not worked with `React` for almost 2 years, the error is probably obvious but I am not getting it so far...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be hitting [this issue (react-bulma-compoenents GitHub)](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components/issues/20).

> The DropdownItem in reality its Dropdown.Item same for the separator.

`NavbarDropdown` should in fact be `Navbar.DropDown`.

I just hit a similar issue with `ButtonGroup` vs `Button.Group`. Not sure why it's not reflected in docs.

The error message is confusing too. What it's saying is, "You asked me to import a certain object, but I can't find it".